# Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App

Tags: facebook, firebase-authentication, ionic4

I'm implementing facebook authentication in my Ionic app and I keep getting the above error.

```js
  facebookLogin() {
    return this.facebook.login(['email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
        console.log('root', res);
        if (res.status === 'connected') {
          console.log('res', res);
          const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider
                              .credential(res.authResponse.accessToken);
          console.log('credential', credential);
          this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .then((response) => {
              this.getUserdetail(res);
              console.log(response);
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log('facebookLogin', error);
            });
          }
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert('error:' + error);
      });
  }
```

The console shows me I'm getting the credentials:

[image]

But afterwards i get the following error:

"Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {"error":{"message":"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"***********"}}"

One thing I noticed is in the config.xml there was already an ID.  I tried changing that to the app ID provided in the facebook developer console to no avail.

I've also searched for solutions in Stack and one suggested disabling App Secret in the facebook dev console but that option is already disabled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Thanks

Comment: Does the App ID found in Firebase Authentication Sign-in method under the Facebook sign-in provider match the App ID in your developers.facebook.com App? Also (if connecting via Android) does the fb_app_id value in android\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml also match the Facebook App ID?

Comment: That was it.  I had to copy the app ID from Facebook to the Firebase facebook login console.